# How do I restore Déjà Dup backups without Déjà Dup?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

So I'm trying to restore my backup files with Déjà Dup, however, each time I enter in the correct password, it keeps asking for it over and over again.

This seems to be a bug, and I have found a couple of bug reports already reported on this issue. I am currently using 12.04, it did not also work in 12.10.

Is there any other software that can restore these backups?

Comment: Where are the backups stored? USB disc? Rackspace? Amazon?

Answer (score 3):

Déjà Dup is a (very useful) frontend to the `duplicity` command line program.

There are instructions on using it to restore backups on the GNOME wiki:

[Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase - GNOME Wiki!](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase)

Answer (score -1):

You can't. You need to reinstall Deja dup manually or google another program to restore your backup.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can reinstall Deja dup and may be you try Back in Time , it's also used in Ubuntu Software Center